# Multiplayer is forcing spectator

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Some friends and I tried for 20+ minutes to get a team deathmatch on Call of Duty 3 Modern Warfare going. For some reason, the first three to choose their class would be playing and the fourth person would be a spectator. We ended the game and started again tons of times, trying everything from "auto-assign" team to choosing the class all within one second of each other.

Any ideas on what may have been going on? I'm new to Call of Duty, is this somehow expected behavior?

Comment: I assume this is local split-screen? This is not expected behavior - did you try restarting the Xbox?

Comment: @SSumner yes, local split-screen. We did restart it just by virtue of trying a different version of COD. I can't remember for sure, but it seems like it happened on the different version also. I'll try again later today with COD 3 MW, maybe it was just a fluke.

Comment: Let me know how that goes. Check and see if it happens on all the versions of CoD you have. If so, try another 4-player game like Halo and see if anything happens there

Comment: Do you mean CoD: Modern Warfare 3 or CoD 4: Modern Warfare? or is it reproducible on other games as well?